# adding all numbers displayed in a single div element

Tags: javascript, html, dom, sum

I would love to know how (if possible) to add all numbers displayed in a div.

```
<div> 1 <br /> 2 <br /> 3 <br /> 4 </div>
```

so, I want to get every number in the div element and add them all, so the output would be 10.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you possibly show me how? Thanks.

Comment: in this specific problem?

Comment: I would break this into an array by the break then summate the values in the array.

Comment: Yes, in this specific problem.

Comment: Could you show us what you tried so far an post a demo to reproduce your particular issue? StakcOverflow is not free codez.

Comment: Can you please show an example of ths davidxd333?

Comment: elclanrs, I haven't really tried anything, I couldn't come up with a solution, im pretty new with javascript myself. I could get around the problem by putting them into different elements, but this way would make my life a lot easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, give the `div` an `id`:

```
<div id="myDiv"> 1 <br /> 2 <br /> 3 <br /> 4 </div>
```

Then:

```
<script>
// Take the content of the div and split it into an array
var numbers = document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML.split(" <br> ");
// Store the length of the array into a variable for repeated use in a loop
var length = numbers.length;
// Create a variable with zero value
var sum = 0;
// Iterate over the elements of the array and ...
// keep adding them to the variable just created
for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){
// Because the elements of the array are strings ...
// Convert them to numbers with the javascript function parseInt()
sum += parseInt(numbers[i]);
}
// Now your sum is ready; alert it or use it in some other way
alert(sum);
</script>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4mQau/)

Answer (score 0):

I tried this.

```
var arr = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].textContent.split(' ')

var sum = arr.reduce(function(a,b){return (+a)+(+b)})

console.log(sum) //prints 10
```